# jQuery $.get and $.parseXML to get Vimeo video duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get duration of specific video on vimeo before I've even loaded it player, so I see no other options rather than make an AJAX call and trying to get information about video. I've prepared the following structure:

```
$.get( "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/8957328.xml", function( data ) {
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data),
  $duration = $(xmlDoc).find("title");
  $('div').html($duration.text());
});
```

As I can say, XML is parsed properly, but I'm not able to get final data, and I don't even have an idea why it's not working. Any help please?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLz8k31v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery itself parses the response for you, i.e. the `data` is already XML-parsed. Just pass the `data` to the jQuery constructor.

```
$.get( "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/8957328.xml", function( data ) {
  var $xmlDoc = $(data),
      $duration = $xmlDoc.find("title");
  $('div').html($duration.text());
});
```

Your code doesn't work as the passed value to the `$.parseXML` is not a string and [the `.parseXML` method returns `null`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/ajax/parseXML.js#L8).

```
jQuery.parseXML = function( data ) {
    var xml;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    // ...
};
```